# How to calculate previous value in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have problem with calculation in table. I would like recive value for 2024 like below
Stawka E = (Stawka E(year 2023) * CPI/100(year 2023)
and for 2025 should be Stawka E = (Stawka E(year 2024) * CPI/100(year 2024) etc..

```
st_opl_prze_dict ={
    "Rok" : [2023,2024,2025,2026,2027],
    "Stawka E" : [2.275, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN],
    "Stawka Ln" : [2.275, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN],
    "CPI" : [11.9, 5.2, 3.6, 3, 2 ]

}
st_opl_prze = pd.DataFrame(st_opl_prze_dict)
st_opl_prze["Stawka E"] = np.where(st_opl_prze["Stawka E"].isnull(),
                                   st_opl_prze["Stawka E"].apply(lambda x: st_opl_prze["Stawka E"].shift(1) * st_opl_prze["CPI"] / 100),
                                   st_opl_prze["Stawka E"])
```

always cod use first value (2024 - 2.275) to calculate.

```
st_opl_prze["Test"] = st_opl_prze["Stawka E"].shift(-1) * (st_opl_prze["CPI"]/100)
print(st_opl_prze)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this instead, I kept the same code using `np.where`

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np


st_opl_prze_dict ={
    "Rok" : [2023,2024,2025,2026,2027],
    "Stawka E" : [2.275, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN],
    "Stawka Ln" : [2.275, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN],
    "CPI" : [11.9, 5.2, 3.6, 3, 2 ]

}
st_opl_prze_dict


st_opl_prze = pd.DataFrame(st_opl_prze_dict)
st_opl_prze
```

I suggest this `for` loop :

```
for i in range(0,st_opl_prze.shape[0]):
    st_opl_prze["Stawka E"] = np.where(st_opl_prze["Stawka E"].isnull(),
                                   st_opl_prze["Stawka E"].shift(1)* st_opl_prze["CPI"].shift(1) / 100,
                                   st_opl_prze["Stawka E"])
st_opl_prze
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a loop, you can vectorize your code with [`cumprod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumprod.html):

```
st_opl_prze.loc[st_opl_prze.index[1:],
                'Stawka E'] = (st_opl_prze['CPI']
                               .iloc[1:].div(100).add(1).cumprod()
                               .mul(st_opl_prze['Stawka Ln'].iloc[0])
                              )
```

Output:

```
    Rok  Stawka E  Stawka Ln   CPI
0  2023  2.275000      2.275  11.9
1  2024  2.393300        NaN   5.2
2  2025  2.479459        NaN   3.6
3  2026  2.553843        NaN   3.0
4  2027  2.604919        NaN   2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of using `np.where`

```
for i in range(1, len(st_opl_prze)):
    st_opl_prze.loc[i, 'Stawka E'] = st_opl_prze.loc[i-1, 'Stawka E'] * (1 + st_opl_prze.loc[i, 'CPI'] / 100)
```

Your original code wasn't working because it wasn't using the updated "Stawka E" values when calculating for the next year. It was only using the initial values.

I fixed it by going through each year one by one and updating the "Stawka E" for that year based on the "Stawka E" from the year before and the "CPI" for the current year. This way, each year's calculation is correctly based on the updated value from the year before.